# Fat tires, need a front brake

Tags: tire, brakes

I’ve got Ultradynamico’s Rose (42.??) tires on my Encore 700c Road Wheels (with machined walls) on my Crust Florida Man bike which has a hole for a brake on the fork crown.

I’m having trouble finding a brake that will fit over these silly tires and touch the rim appropriately. Ideally the brake would be somewhat nice and kinda Gucci, the rest of the bike is set up with White Industries and Phil stuff.

Comment: Maybe silly question, but wouldn't a frame called "Florida man" that allows installing working front brake be true to its name?

Answer (score 2):

According to the build [instructions for the frame](https://crustbikes.com/collections/frames/products/florida-man).

> It doesn’t have any cable guides, disc, or canti brake mounts to speak of, but you can run a side or center pull brake with ~70mm of reach up front with a 700c wheel. You can run a front brake with a 650b wheel set, by using Dia Compe's MX1000 side pull.

So, about 70mm of reach puts you in BMX brake territory.

Cust, and others, sell the [DIA-COMPE MX1000](https://crustbikes.com/collections/brakes-levers/products/dia-compe-mx1000) brake in a variety of colors.
The longest reach side pull brake I am aware of. These are the long reach old school BMX brakes you will want if you're trying to run a front brake on a 650b Florida Man.

> Details:
> Made in Taiwan
> Drop Forged Aluminum Arms
> Colors- Polished, Red, Blue, or Gold
> Short Pull (Side Pull)
> Position- Front or Rear
> Brake Reach- 73-92mm
> Width (Between Arms)- ~65mm
> Weight- 210g

In my experience with these brakes they did slow me down but they weren't the best stoppers. They were improved by adding a high performance brake pad.

Odyssey and Tektro also makes a long reach side pull. Dia Compe also makes a dual pivot long reach brake - the MX806

Another brake Crust, and others, sell is the [DIA-COMPE LONG REACH CENTERPULL CALIPER](https://crustbikes.com/collections/brakes-levers/products/dia-compe-long-reach-centerpull-calipers)

> Details:
> Made in Taiwan
> Drop Forged Aluminum Arms
> Colors- Black or Polished
> Short Pull (Center Pull)
> Position- Front or Rear
> Brake Reach- 60-78mm
> Width (Between Arms)- ~60mm
> Come with soft grey Dia-Compe pads.
> Weight- Front: 201g (7.1oz) | Rear: 194g (6.85oz)

Dia Compe brake model to reach table
[image]

None of these are intended as product recommendations

Answer (score 1):

You're unlikely to find a caliper brake that can straddle a 42mm tyre comfortably.

V Brakes are more likely to do it, but the mounting system is different to the point of needing a replacement fork.

Disk brakes would be the best option for you, but that needs a new hub, rotor, caliper, and fork.

The easiest solution is to forgo the 42mm tyre and drop down to a 38, 35, or 32mm.